# Finding Critical Path?

Tags: graph, uml, project-management, activity-diagram

Can you please tell me what would be critical path of the following diagram. Is it:
`a->c->f`  or `a->d->g` 
or both

**I drew the network diagram using the following table:**

[image]

**Network Diagram:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the network diagram is correct, `a->c->f` has a cost of 6 + 6 + 9 = 21.  `a->d->g` has a cost of 6 + 7 + 7 = 20.  So `a->c->f` would be the longest (and hence critical) path.

Please note that I did not take into account any of the crash durations, costs, etc. from the original table.  People should work 40-hour work weeks, not "crash". :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for Bob and Eric for explaining in detail. appreciate it.

Comment: @Eric Galluzzo Thanks a lot for Bob and Eric for explaining in detail. appreciate it.

Comment: I especially liked this anwser for the "people should not crash" part :)